# Angular2+ - Using component in multiple modules

Tags: angular, typescript

Importing a component named "TemperatureComponent" into a module named "DashboardModule" and declaring + exporting it there:

```
import { TemperatureComponent } from './temperature/temperature.component';
import { TemperatureDraggerComponent } from './temperature/temperature-dragger/temperature-dragger.component';
//...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //...
  ],
  declarations: [
    //...
    TemperatureDraggerComponent,
    TemperatureComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
      TemperatureComponent,
      TemperatureDraggerComponent,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Works there fine.
I'm trying to get that same component to work in a different module using its selector,  (the selector also works fine in DashboardModule). I try to do this by importing DashboardModule:

```
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { DashboardModule } from '../dashboard/dashboard.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //...
    DashboardModule,
  ],
})
export class DiceModule { }
```

Then in this second module's HTML, I have the selector as follows:

```
  <div class="col-xxxl-3 col-md-6" *ngFor="let statusCard of statusCards">
    <ngx-status-card [title]="statusCard.title" [type]="statusCard.type">
      <i [ngClass]="statusCard.iconClass"></i>
    </ngx-status-card>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xxxl-3 col-xxl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-6">
    <ngx-temperature></ngx-temperature>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives the error:

> ERROR in src/app/pages/dice/dice.component.html:11:5 - error NG8001:
> 'ngx-temperature' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'ngx-temperature' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngx-temperature' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

Additional code as requested:

**temperature.component.ts**

```
import { NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { Temperature, TemperatureHumidityData } from '../../../@core/data/temperature-humidity';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-temperature',
  styleUrls: ['./temperature.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './temperature.component.html',
})
export class TemperatureComponent implements OnDestroy {

  private alive = true;

  temperatureData: Temperature;
  temperature: number;
  temperatureOff = false;
  temperatureMode = 'cool';

  humidityData: Temperature;
  humidity: number;
  humidityOff = false;
  humidityMode = 'heat';

  theme: any;
  themeSubscription: any;

  constructor(private themeService: NbThemeService,
              private temperatureHumidityService: TemperatureHumidityData) {
    this.themeService.getJsTheme()
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(config => {
      this.theme = config.variables.temperature;
    });

    forkJoin(
      this.temperatureHumidityService.getTemperatureData(),
      this.temperatureHumidityService.getHumidityData(),
    )
      .subscribe(([temperatureData, humidityData]: [Temperature, Temperature]) => {
        this.temperatureData = temperatureData;
        this.temperature = this.temperatureData.value;

        this.humidityData = humidityData;
        this.humidity = this.humidityData.value;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive = false;
  }
}
```

**temperature.component.html**

```
  <nb-tabset fullWidth>

    <nb-tab tabTitle="Temperature">

      <div class="slider-container">
        <ngx-temperature-dragger [(value)]="temperature" (power)="temperatureOff = !$event"
                                 [min]="temperatureData.min" [max]="temperatureData.max" [disableArcColor]="theme.arcEmpty"
                                 [fillColors]="theme.arcFill" [thumbBg]="theme.thumbBg" [thumbBorderColor]="theme.thumbBorder">

          <div class="slider-value-container"  [ngClass]="{ 'off': temperatureOff }">
            <div class="value temperature h1">
              {{ temperatureOff ? '--' : (temperature | ngxRound) }}
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
              Celsius
            </div>
          </div>
        </ngx-temperature-dragger>
      </div>

      <nb-radio-group [(ngModel)]="temperatureMode" name="temperature-mode">
        <nb-radio value="cool">
          <i class="nb-snowy-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
        <nb-radio value="warm">
          <i class="nb-sunny-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
        <nb-radio value="heat">
          <i class="nb-flame-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
        <nb-radio value="fan">
          <i class="nb-loop-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
      </nb-radio-group>
    </nb-tab>

    <nb-tab tabTitle="Humidity">

      <div class="slider-container">
        <ngx-temperature-dragger [(value)]="humidity" (power)="humidityOff = !$event"
                                 [min]="humidityData.min" [max]="humidityData.max" [disableArcColor]="theme.arcEmpty"
                                 [fillColors]="theme.arcFill" [thumbBg]="theme.thumbBg" [thumbBorderColor]="theme.thumbBorder">

          <div class="slider-value-container"  [ngClass]="{ 'off': humidityOff }">
            <div class="value humidity h1">
              {{ humidityOff ? '--' : (humidity | ngxRound) }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </ngx-temperature-dragger>
      </div>

      <nb-radio-group [(ngModel)]="humidityMode" name="humidity-mode">
        <nb-radio value="cool">
          <i class="nb-snowy-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
        <nb-radio value="warm">
          <i class="nb-sunny-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
        <nb-radio value="heat">
          <i class="nb-flame-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
        <nb-radio value="fan">
          <i class="nb-loop-circled"></i>
        </nb-radio>
      </nb-radio-group>
    </nb-tab>
  </nb-tabset>
</nb-card>
```

TL;DR: Trying to share a component between Modules A & B by:

1. Importing, declaring & exporting it in Module A.
2. Importing Module A into Module B.

Why isn't the selector working and instead giving me an error?

**P.S:** Both modules are imported into a parent module named Pages. I'm not sure if that's good practice or if that is in any way relevant.

Comment: Your code looks ok, please share TemperatureComponent class also.

Comment: Added temperature.component.ts and temperature.component.html.

Comment: I am not seeing any issue. Have you modified component selector prefix as **ngx** in **angular.json** file?

Comment: ```"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "ngx",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "ngx"
    }
  },```

Comment: The selector works in the first module though (DashboardModule), so it should work in the second one as well. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Yes you are right, looks strange.

Comment: Fixed it. Forgot to import the component as required. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not importing the component (DiceComponent) into the second module (DiceModule). The code now works after importing it into the module as follows:

```
import {
  NbActionsModule,
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbRadioModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbListModule,
  NbIconModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';

import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DiceComponent } from './dice.component'; //<-- this is the line I forgot to add.
import { DashboardModule } from '../dashboard/dashboard.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ThemeModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbActionsModule,
    NbRadioModule,
    NbSelectModule,
    NbListModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    DashboardModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DiceComponent, // <-- Component declared as required.
  ],
})
export class DiceModule { }
```